# Spring Cloud Gateway routes do not work and Hystrix Dashboard crashed loading

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, hystrix, spring-cloud-gateway

In a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BnknNTN8icw) from youtube the author to use **Spring Cloud Gateway, Hystrix, Netflix**, and configure routes with **application.yml**, but when I try to send data from the endpoint I just hang on the Hystrix Dashboard "**Loading** ...", in the tutorial works well...

hystrix.stream work well, put him in Histrix dashboard and only show "loading"

I tried another tutorial, but the problem persists again!

**Maven Dependencies**

```
spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client
spring-cloud-starter-config
lombok
spring-boot-starter-data-jpa
spring-boot-starter-web
spring-cloud-starter-hystrix:2.7.3.RELEASE
<spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR10</spring-cloud.version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: API-GATEWAY
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: USER-SERVICE
          uri: lb://USER-SERVICE
          predicates:
            - Path=/user/**
          filters:
            - name: CircuitBreaker
              args:
                name: USER-SERVICE
                fallbackuri: forward:/userServiceFallBack
        - id: DEPARTMENT-SERVICE
          uri: lb://DEPARTMENT-SERVICE
          predicates:
            - Path=/department/**
          filters:
            - name: CircuitBreaker
              args:
                name: DEPARTMENT-SERVICE
                fallbackuri: forward:/departmentServiceFallBack


@Bean
@LoadBalanced
public RestTemplate restTemplate(){
    return new RestTemplate();
}
```

If use @EnableCircuitBreaker working very well , the problem is use application.yml to configure spring cloud routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simple, **API-GATEWAY** where **hystrix.stream** is used on port **8789**, and **USER-SERVICE** on port **9001**, so you need to use the API-GATEWAY port with the user's endpoint to work the metrics.

```
API-GATEWAY port: 8789
USER-SERVICE port: 9001
```

Problem:

```
API-GATEWAY - http://localhost:8789/acturator/hystrix.stream
USER-SERVICE save user - http://localhost:9001/user/
```

Solution:

```
API-GATEWAY - http://localhost:8789/acturator/hystrix.stream
USER-SERVICE save user - http://localhost:8789/user/
```

Metrics now work well and the Hystrix Dashboard can work correctly.